# Help finding dimensions of a box (Precalc 12)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question -

> A sheet metal fabricator makes boxes from sheet of steel. Each sheet
>   of steel has an area of $1500\text{cm}^2$. $6$cm squares are cut from each corner
>   and the edges are bent up to form a box with a volume of $3456\text{cm}^3$. What
>   are the dimensions of each box? (Accurate to $3$ places of a decimal)

I found this write up online

```
original length --- l
original width ---- w
so lw = 1500
w = 1500/l

new length = l-12
new width = w-12 , you are cutting 6 cm off on each end
new height = 6
volume = 6(l-12)(w-12)= 3456
(l-12)(w-12) = 576
lw - 12l - 12w + 144 = 576
1500 - 12(l+w) + 144 = 576
1068 = 12(l+w)
l+w = 89

l + 1500/l = 89
l^2 - 89l + 1500 = 0
using the formula,
l = appr 66.4 or l = 22.6
then w = 22.6, or w = 66.4
area = 22.6(66.4) = 1500.6 , not bad
volume = 6(22.6-12)(66.4-12) = 3459.84 , acceptable
```

His calculations are obviously off. I am confused on how he got the measurement for the height when it isn't mentioned in the question. I am wondering how to get an accurate measurement, if anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: The height is 6 because they cut 6cm squares from each corner of the box

Comment: https://gyazo.com/0815fa584bd4a7734c252d1ab4a8fbce
I pictured it like this, with an open top.

Comment: The resulting box will have three interesting parameters. Can you find and insert them in your sketch?

Comment: I believe I understand now lol. 
https://gyazo.com/5995283d0a6df625bcd15e8a6e710b87
Hope that's correct. :)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Hi mvw, I forgot to add. What formula do they use to find the width/length from  the combined width and length value of 89? I tried googling and I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation is quite clear and correct.

The original dimensions are length, $l$ and width $w$ with the area $lw=1500$

The volume of the box is $$v= 6(l-12)(w-12)$$ which is the product of new dimensions after cutting and bending.

Please read the solution one more time and you will follow it thoroughly.

Comment: I'm going to chalk it up to me being tired, I had a brain fart and couldn't understand how he got the height but it is very clear to me now. Thank you.